# Cannot break out of while loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, breakpoints

Cannot break out of while loop in python:
I tried merging the code all together with no main and getheight functions, and it still gives me an infinite loop.

```
def main():
    x = 0
    while x not in range (1,23):
        getheight()
        if x in range (1,23):
            break
    for i in range (x):
        for j in range (x - j):
            print (" ", end="")
        for j in range (x):
            print ("#", end="")
        print ("  ", end="")
        for j in range (x):
            print ("#", end="")
        "\n"

def getheight():
    x = input("Give me a positive integer no more than 23 \n")
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: because your x in main is always 0, `x=getheight()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` in `main()` is a local variable that is *independent* from the `x` variable in `getheight()`. You are returning the new value from the latter but areignoring the returned value. Set `x` in `main` from the function call result:

```
while x not in range (1,23):
    x = getheight()
    if x in range (1,23):
        break
```

You also need to fix your `getheight()` function to return an *integer*, not a string:

```
def getheight():
    x = input("Give me a positive integer no more than 23 \n")
    return int(x)
```

Comment: I added the "x =". But still gives me an infinite loop. I think it's because the initial declaration of x in main. But if I remove it, Python wouldn't get into the while loop. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @user627154: Your code won't work *at all unless* `x` has been assigned before the loop. If you removed the `x = 0` and not capture the return value of `getheight()`, then you must have a global name `x` that happens to be set to a valid value.

Comment: @user627154: Ah, I missed that you are returning the `input()`` value unchanged, so a *string*, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Return does not mean that it will automatically update whatever variable name in main matches the return variable. If you do not store this return value, the return value will be gone. Hence you must do

```
x=getheight()
```

to update your variable x