# Break out of while loop within an if statement in an function

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am currently stuck on something
I am trying to break out of a while loop that is like this

```
while True
    if blah blah
        function()
        if blah blah:
            #break while loop
```

I tried a lot of methods but I can't seem to get it working, can anyone teach me?

EDIT: I fixed the example I typed above.

Comment: `break` 
However, I would write this code differently, 
flag = True
while flag:
    "do stuff"
    if blah blah:
        flag = False

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318622/cannot-break-out-of-while-loop-in-python

Comment: just add `break` to that if. I think you meant something else so show us the real code because this example is most likely not what you intended it to be

Comment: What do you mean by "in a function"? Is the `if` condition actually inside `function()`? Because that's a more difficult and more interesting question than the one posed.

Comment: `break` should do what you want. If it doesn't post a [mcve] of actual Python code that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what a `break` statement does.

```
while True:
    function()
    if blah blah:
        break
```

Of course, if possible you should move the test to the loop condition.

```
while not blah blah:
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to break the loop from "inside" the function, there are several ways of doing it:

- return True/False from the function, and check the return value in the loop
- raise a special exception from the function and catch it inside the loop

Examples:

```
# example 1
def function():
    if cloudy and not umbrella:
        print "no good to stay outside"
        return False
    return True

while nice_weather:
    if not function():
        break


# example 2
class RunHome(Exception):
    pass

def function():
    if thunderstorm:
        raise RunHome()

while enjoying:
    try:
        function()
    except RunHome as re:
        break
```

Depending on what actually the function and the loop do, some other techniques may be suitable as well.